# MDX IIF statement to calculate new member basing on measure and hierarchy leaves

Tags: ssas, mdx, sql-server-data-tools, dimensional-modeling

I have a simple Data Cube for computing shared expenditures with one measure `Amount` and some dimensions and hierarchies but interesting one would be `Relationship`. It describes who bought something for whom. It's structure is:

- Who
- For whom
- Relationship key

I am trying to code a calculation representing debt. For example if I bought something for sharing usage it would be half of `0.5 * Amount`. On the other hand, if I bought something for myself it would be `0 * Amount`.

As far I tried following calculation:

```
IIF(
[dimRelationship].[Relationship].currentMember = [dimRelationship].[Relationship].[RelatonshipID].&[MeShared],
[Measures].[Amount]*0.5,
[Measures].[Amount]*0)
```

It works good only at lowest `RelationshipID` level. When I roll-up browsered pivot-table it is acting according to else-expression. That is not really surprising because hierarchy's `currentMember` is not `MeShared` anymore. Another bad thing that total aggregation work neither - it would be most important as a general summary. Is there any suffix like .LeafMember or something like that which could help me perform this calculation?

Thank you in advance!

Best regards,

Max!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In you fact table add another column, in this column store the "Amount" multiplied by the relationshipID for that particular row. This will address you issue right out the box

Comment: I added column to `dimRelationship` `refund` For example. If personA bought something for personA then its 0. If personA bought something for B it is 1. If personA bought something for common usage it is 0.5.

I added a calculation `[Debt]` as:
`[Measures].[Ammount]*[dimRelationship].[refund].memberValue`
but it still doesn't aggregate. It works fine on lowest level, but on higher ones it says #ARG! while browsing with Excel.

Comment: @Maks you are adding this to the calculated measures. You need to add this to the Fact Table that your project reads from . In that fact table add another column, which has the Amount multiplied by the Relationship and store it for each fact row. Now use this measure in your cube.Your issue is design time

Comment: Okay it works. Thank you. I always thought that idea of OLAP systems is that it can compute some thing in effective way without need of adding additional columns into source tables. It seems like my OLAP understanding is quite lacking. Thank you for you time and hints!

Answer (score 0):

Try SCOPE statement.

Firstly, create new calculation `[Debt Calculation] as [Measures].[Amount]*0 /* as ELSE-scenario */`

Then create a SCOPE:

```
SCOPE([Debt Calculation],[dimRelationship].[Relationship].[RelatonshipID].&[MeShared]);
THIS=[Measures].[Amount]*0.5;
END SCOPE;
```

If it's the lowest level of hierarchy and is a dimension key (which is used as a link to measure groups), it will re-calc higher levels of this dimension automatically. Please post a result here if not.

Comment: It still works only for lowest hierarchy level. It doesn't sum up for higher levels of dimension.